# How to generate tab separated output using saveastextfile in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using Scala, and I want saveAsTextFile to directly save the result as tab separated, like, for example:

```
a 1
b 4
c 5
```

(space is tab)

I just want to use `saveAsTextFile` (not print), and when I have like `RDD[(String, Double)]`, I cannot use

```
ranks = ranks.map( f => f._1 +"\t"+f._2)
```

It says the type does not match, I guess is because `f._1` is string and `f._2` is a double?

Comment: This answer provided is correct. Please accept it so we can close the question !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only mistake in your code is trying to re-assign the result of the mapping into the same `ranks` variable - I'm assuming `ranks` has type `RDD[(String, Double)]` so indeed you can't assign it with a value of type `RDD[String]`. Simply use a separate variable:

```
val ranks: RDD[(String, Double)] = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 1D), ("b", 4D)))
val tabSeparated: RDD[String] = ranks.map(f => f._1 +"\t"+f._2)
tabSeparated.saveAsTextFile("./test.tsv")
```

In general, it's almost always better to use `val`s and not `var`s to prevent such mistakes.

NOTE: a perhaps cleaner way to convert a tuple (of any size) into a tab-delimited string:

```
ranks.map(_.productIterator.mkString("\t"))
```